# Como recuperar sessão do usuário

Tags: java, sql, java-ee, session, spring-security

eu queria apenas recuperar a sessão de um usuário. 
Eu tenho uma classe chamada **UsuarioSistema**, que identifica que usuário está logando. 
Nesse classe, eu pego a sessão e jogo para um objeto.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "usuarioLogado")
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioSistema extends User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Usuario usuario;

    public UsuarioSistema(Usuario usuario, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha(), authorities);
        this.usuario = usuario;

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("usuarioLogado", usuario);

    }


    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
}
```

Eu tento recuperar essa sessão na hora do usuário gerar um simulado, ou seja, em uma bean. Entretanto, vem sempre null.

```
@Named
@viewScoped
public class GerarSimuladoBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest); 

      @Transactional
    public void gerarSimulado() {

        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) req.getSession();
        Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");

        //......
}
```

Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado, e porque não consigo recuperar o usuário?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está em como você recupera a sessão. Isso deveria ser feito por meio do FacesContext dentro do método em que você deseja recuperar a sessão. Seria mais ou menos assim:

```
@Transactional
public void gerarSimulado() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession)fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");
    // ...
}
```

Você deve se lembrar que você não pode colocar dois atributos na sessão com o mesmo nome.

Este nome vai para a sessão aqui (usuarioLogado):

```
@ManagedBean(name = "usuarioLogado")
```

Troque por outro ou use o ManagedBean:

```
session.getAttribute("usuario");
```

Answer (score 3):

o Leonardo resolveu o meu problema. No Final das contas o código ficou assim:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "usuarioLogado")
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioSistema extends User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Usuario usuario;

    public UsuarioSistema(Usuario usuario,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha(), authorities);
        this.usuario = usuario;

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("identificaUsuario", usuario);

    }
    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

}
```

E o método do gerarSimulado Ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
public void gerarSimulado() {

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        Usuario usuario = (Usuario)session.getAttribute("identificaUsuario"); 

 }
```

}

Com a dica que o Leonardo forneceu, foi possível pegar a sessão do usuário e fazendo o cast Corretamente nessa linha `Usuario usuario = (Usuario)session.getAttribute("identificaUsuario");` além de trocar os nomes dos setAttribute e getAttribute foi possível conseguir o que eu queria, que era apenas os dados do usuário.

Espero que possa ajudar alguém!

Comment: Com certeza ajudará sim.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, no trecho:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) req.getSession();
Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("nomeDoSeuBean");
```

Você está tentando pegar o managedBean, não o atributo contido nele. Para isso, você deverá fazer o seguinte:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) req.getSession();
UsuarioSistema bean = (UsuarioSistema)  session.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");
Usuario usuario = bean.getUsuario();
```

**Edit**

Agora que percebi que você está colocando o atributo na sessão e depois tenta recuperar ele em uma requisição. Tente utilizar o mesmo escopo que foi armazenado o atributo, no caso, no session.

Comment: bom dia, obrigado por responder amigo. O problema é que nessa linha.
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) req.getSession();

O objeto req está null, sabe me dizer o porquê?